# Unable to delete Amazon S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Please help to delete s3 bucket.

1. I have created Kubernetes Cluster during cluster build created S3 bucket, after deleting cluster unable to delete S3 bucket.
2. when tried to delete from S3 console getting Unknown Error (An unexpected error occurred).
3. Tried to delete by `aws s3 rb s3://<bucket name> --force` getting below error

```
fatal error: An error occurred (NoSuchBucket) when calling the ListObjects operation: The specified bucket does not exist
```

4. Tried to run `aws s3 rm s3://<bucket name>/foo*`
   But no luck in resolving the issue could you please help to me to resove the issue.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it fits more as an AWS support ticket

Comment: Are you sure that the bucket still exists? Does `aws s3 ls s3://<bucket name>` finds the bucket?

Comment: Yes i am able to find bucket in S3

Comment: I have basic free account, if this need to for support i need to upgrade my plan.

Comment: In that case there is probably little SO can help you with, since it seems you are doing things as you should and the problem is on AWS side. The only option we can rule out is a typo, so if you'd like to post a screenshot of the `ls` command working and the `rb` command failing that could help with that.

Comment: Deleting a bucket might take a bit of time. Please check again the next day and you'll probably find it has been deleted.

Comment: I have checked and bucket got deleted next day. Thanks all for the support.